# Apply any over rows

Tags: r

In R the any-Function is applied over columns that the result is boolean. 
What is the best way, to apply it row by row? My target in this case is to do a recode for A, if any of A, B or C is 1 or 6. (If TRUE TEST$NEW should be 101)

Here my DataFrame:

```
  A B C D
  1 1 1 "A"
  2 1 2 "B" 
  3 6 3 "C"
  5 3 5 "D"
```

It could be done in this way, but there should be a smarter solution:

```
TEST$NEW <- ifelse(TEST$A == 1 | TEST$B == 1 | TEST$C == 1 | TEST$A == 6 | TEST$B == 6 | TEST$C == 6, 101, NA)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
TEST$NEW <- ifelse(apply(TEST,1,function(x) any(x==1|x==6)),101,NA)
```

Comment: thats what I m looking for! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it, but there may be a simpler one :

```
df <- read.table(textConnection('A B C D
1 1 1 "A"
2 1 2 "B" 
3 6 3 "C"
5 3 5 "D"'), header=TRUE)

test <- rowSums(sapply(df[,c("A","B","C")], function(v) v %in% c(1,6)))
df$TEST <- ifelse(test>0, 101, NA)
```

Which gives :

```
  A B C D TEST
1 1 1 1 A  101
2 2 1 2 B  101
3 3 6 3 C  101
4 5 3 5 D   NA
```

Comment: What I m looking for is a function that works similar to SPSS. There you have the syntax any(A, 1, 6) | any(B, 1, 6) ....

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

```
TEST$NEW <- 101 * apply(TEST, 1, function(x) any(x %in% c(1, 6))) ^ NA

  A B C D NEW
1 1 1 1 A 101
2 2 1 2 B 101
3 3 6 3 C 101
4 5 3 5 D  NA
```

Comment: Interesting; *a priori* I would have expected that `TRUE^NA` and `FALSE^NA` would both be defined as `NA` or would both be equal to themselves (especially given that a power of a logical only seems to make sense for non-negative integers), but given `c(1,0)^NA == c(1,NA)` it's clear enough where that's coming from.